# Changing Lines in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a chart in SSRS, and I would like to use different types of lines for each series.  I would like to have one line dotted, another solid, etc.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right click** on series and goto series properties

[image]

Goto border tab and **change the line style**.

[image]